# ajaxStart and ajaxStop for a specific event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I bind an `ajaxStart` function for a specific event, using :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
  alert("started");
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
  alert("Ended");
});
```

Tried this code but it runs whenever autocomplete starts.

Scenario must be like this : whenever I submit a form, that function will be called.
But when I'm just fetching values using autocomplete via ajax, `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` shouldn't be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
      url :'your url',
      data: {
           //data to send if any
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success:function(msg){
           //eqv to ajaxstop if OK
      },
      beforeSend:function(){
           //before ajax starts
      },
      error:function(){
           //failure in ajax
      }
 });
```

Comment: This is the first answer and it worked, so i'll choose this as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 3):

> But when I'm just fetching values using autocomplete via ajax,
>   ajaxStart and ajaxStop shouldn't be called.

You can create a boolean variable to keep track of whether user is typing or not something like:

```
<script>
var isTyping = false;

// inside your autocomplete handler set isTyping to true

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    if (! isTyping) alert("started");
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    if (! isTyping) alert("Ended");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better if you uses the main function and it's sub-functions.

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'url_to_page'
 beforeSend: function(req){ //Before the request is taking off},
 error: function(req){ //If there were a error},
 success: function(req){ //When it all was done}
});
```