# ajaxStop for a specific event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010410/ajaxstart-and-ajaxstop-for-a-specific-event) but it did not help much because of **success:function**. it do not understand completion of Ajax response. Do anyone know how to use Ajax stop for specific events ?

**Detail** : I have an Ajax code which sends a request and I want it to do something when it gets a response. I do that by the following function but it gets all documents of Ajax and I cant add any Ajax to the page.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                ....;
                alert("start");
});
```

Comment: why you use `$(document).ajaxStop`

Comment: Because i want the program to get response from requested urls.

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxStop` is meant to be used for a global AJAX completion behavior.  You probably want to use a regular `complete` handler:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "some/path.php",
  complete: function() { alert("start"); }
});
```

or alternatively you can use the `always` promise method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
}).always(function() {
  alert("start");
});
```

UPDATE:

Looking at your comments below, you might actually want to use success (especially when you are interested in the `response`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "some/path.php",
  success: function(response) { alert(response); }
});
```

or alternatively you can use the `done` promise method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
}).done(function(response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

However, it is important to note that both of those methods only execute when you receive a successful response from the server (status code 200).

Comment: I have tested complete function ,it trigger when the request completed it don't wait for response.

Comment: There is no difference between "request completed" and "wait for response". The request is complete when the response arrives. What makes you even think that there is no response?

Comment: Believe me , i have tested it , it trigger when it send request.

Comment: I have no idea how you tested that, but `complete` always executes when the request is done, not when it is sent. You might be confusing `complete` with `success` though, because `complete` doesn't provide you with a response.  Only `success` does.  I will update my answer with some more details.

Comment: Why don't you share your exact code that you used to test it... there might be a problem in that code.